# Holomorphicity of period map for framed families of elliptic curves? Reference?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, complex-geometry, modular-forms, moduli-space

Let $\pi : X \to T$ be a framed family of elliptic curves (i.e. we have a family of $a(t), b(t) \in H_1(X_t; \mathbb{Z})$ that have $\langle a(t), b(t) \rangle$ in the intersection pairing). One can get a map $\Phi : T \to \mathbb{H}$ (upper half plane) by $\Phi(t) = \int_{a(t)} w_t / \int_{b(t)} w_t$.

Can anyone point me towards a reference where it is proven in detail that $\Phi$ is holomorphic. The notes I'm reading (by Richard Hain - https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1803.pdf ) are very sketchy about this - they gave me enough to believe that it is holomorphic, but I want to know how to work with the details.

Comment: Say the elliptic curve is $\mathbb{C}/ (\mathbb{Z}+\tau(t) \mathbb{Z})$ then $\Phi(t) = \tau(t)$ and it is holomorphic by definition of $X,\pi$. In general your family of elliptic curves can be defined differently so you'll need the holomorphic differentials, but it won't change the idea

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for the (useful, though tautological) example. While it improves my ability to believe in this fact, it doesn't really clarify how to make the general statement precise. The argument I want to understand has three parts 1) The construction of a differential form (which involves things like the conormal exact sequence, and presumably some homological trickery) 2) A proof that integrating a family of differential forms over a continuously varying family of 1-cycles gives a holomorphic function. 3) A passage from the framing to a specific family of chains.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd say the objective is to define the ($\mathbb{C}$) universal elliptic curve $E_j : y^2 = 4 x^3-\frac{27j}{j-1728} x- \frac{27j}{j-1728}$ and to say that $ \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})\simeq E_{j(\tau)}$ where $\tau \mapsto j(\tau)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ (and clearly $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ invariant)

Comment: @user1952009 The objective in terms of where the notes are headed?